# The comments section is a train wreck - which comment do I flag for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

I recently saw [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/88874/37078) on Cooking.SE. The comments section there is a disaster, so I flagged for moderator attention on the **first** comment on the answer. However, I'm not sure if I should have flagged the very first comment, or the first comment *that went off-topic* and started the train wreck in the first place.

If the *entire* comments section is a mess, *which comment should I flag for moderator attention*?

To be clear, in this question I don't care about whether or not the answer is low-quality, NAA, should be deleted, etc. I'm focusing on the fact that *comments need to be cleaned up*.

Comment: It depends. If you want all comments gone because they are all obsolete, I normally flag the answer and ask to have them all nuked. An SO mod told me that the threshold is around 4-5 comments where you flag the post. If you want to cherry pick it becomes somewhat harder but if it is within *keep the first and last two comments* I normally give it go in a single post flag. If that can't be done, I cherry pick and flag the comments one-by-one, maybe with a custom flag if the mod might wonder why these flags are raised in such short timeframe.

Comment: I use a custom flag on the comment where the problem starts. In that custom flag, I point out that comments from there on are getting out of hand, and need to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

For bringing the matter to the attention of the ♦ moderators, I'd say it doesn't matter. You can even flag the post itself, as long as you state clearly what the moderator should *do*, i.e. "the comments section is a train wreck" isn't really helpful as flag text, because the first comment does serve to indicate why it's a bad answer and should (IMHO) be kept.

As @JonClements correctly notes in the comments, it's better *not* to choose a 'good, worthy of keeping' comment, because it's hard to mark a flag on that comment as helpful while simultaneously keeping the comment itself.

Comment: Might be worth noting when you flag a comment that doesn't need removal to indicate others do - the only way for a mod to mark it helpful is to delete the comment flagged and then go and undelete it after which is a little awkward.